# NodeJS - LDAPJS Error : events.js:160 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: javascript, node.js, ldapjs

all I am new to nodejs and I am facing this issue while executing my node file. I am on centos 7. When I am trying to connect to LDAP using LDAPJS. It works fine when LDAP is available but then it cannot connect to server it show this weird error :

> events.js:160
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 172.24.130.203:389
>       at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
>       at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
>       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1099:14)

I want to catch this error and show a proper error message.

I have tried using this :

```
 rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean --force && npm install
```

But it did not help.

My package.json file is :

```
{
  "name": "package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "For LDAP ",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "ldap": "^0.7.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "ldapjs"
  ],
  "author": "Rajan",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

And this is index.js file :

```
var ldap = require('ldapjs');
var http = require('http');
var assert = require('assert');


var client = ldap.createClient({
    url: 'ldap://172.24.130.203/dc=india,dc=bizrtc,dc=com'
});

var basedn = "dc=test,dc=test,dc=test";

var opts = {
  filter: '(ipPhone=*)',
  scope: 'sub',
  attributes: ['ipPhone','mail','name','description']
};

client.bind('username', 'mysecret', function (err) {

client.search('dc=india,dc=bizrtc,dc=com', opts, function (err, search) {
    search.on('searchEntry', function (entry) {
      var user = entry.object;
      console.log("Users are " + user.ipPhone + "  Display Name is  " + user.name + " E-Mail is " + user.mail + " Password is  " + user.description);

    });

  });
});


client.unbind(function(err) {
  assert.ifError(err);
});
```

Comment: Show your LDAP connect code. The error says `Unhandled 'error' event`, so that's all you need to do: handle the error. How is cleaning the module cache going to help? You need to write some kind of `catch` or `.on("error")` code.

Comment: @ChrisG I have added my code in question

Comment: @ChrisG - yes exactly but i don't understand why it says error in some `events.js:160 throw er`

Comment: It got inherited from events https://nodejs.org/api/events.html

Answer (score 1):

As it seems, the client catchs socket errors and re-emits these:
[Client - error](https://github.com/joyent/node-ldapjs/blob/master/lib/client/client.js#L1165)

So you should be fine with something like

```
client.on('error', err => { console.error(err) })
```

Comment: That still does not catch the error - i don't know why

Comment: I tried it - for me the error is caught. Where do you call client.on(...)? (please add that in your source). BTW, your package.json has a dependency on "ldap", but you require "ldapjs". These appear to be two different packages, although they might look, or in fact are, compatible. I wonder how your index.js can run after you replaced node_modules.